# When designing an android Interface, what size should my initial canvas be?

Tags: android

When designing an android Interface, what size should my initial canvas be? I want to make a layout that is compatible for every type of screen - is it possible to start at a specific, large design, and scale down from there? i.e., 960x720?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try get screen size:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
```

And orientation:

```
public int getScreenOrientation() {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        return 1; // Portrait Mode
    }else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        return 2;   // Landscape mode
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid fix amounts of pixels in your layout.
Par example, this code will draw two Buttons, each one half as width as the screen:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Tab1_Buttonline1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/function_datasync" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Daten Sync"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" 
        android:maxLines="1">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/function_docsync" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Datei Sync"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" 
        android:maxLines="1">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

You also might define different layouts for different resolutions by usin the drawable-hdpi / -mdpi or -ldpi foders, ain order to define different drawables.

Last but not least, if you are forced to set a specific height or weight of a control use eg.

```
android:layout_margin="5dip"
```

because of the "dip" the margin now will appear similar on every resolution.